# How to get rowindex in GridView when OnCommand argument used in the field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblViewDetail" runat="server" style="text-decoration:underline;"  OnCommand="ViewSummary" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ShowlinkDetail") %>' Text='View Detail' />
```

I have one Menthod in .cs file and this method name call in the datafield

```
OnCommand="ViewSummary"
private void ViewSummary()
{
     //code
}
```

when I click in the grid view on the lable control then I want to get the Rowindex.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The **OnCommand** for your linkbutton would be something like this

```
protected void lnk_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   // The Namingcontainer would be Gridrow
   // You can get the rowindex in this fashion
    ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it will return your current row. you don't need to row index..

```
if(e.CommandName == "")
{
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **LinkButton**:

```
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
```

in `.cs`:

```
protected void gv_CommDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //Here you can get the index.

                if (e.CommandName == "ViewSummary")
                {
                   drp_Comm.Items.FindByValue(((HiddenField)gv_CommDetails.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("hdn_CommCode")).Value).Selected = true;
                   txt_CommDescription.Text =gv_CommDetails.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }

        }
```