# Get the rowindex of gridview inside repeater on checkbox checked changed event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview inside repeater controls item template.Gridview has a checkbox field.On checked changed event of checkbox i need the rowindex of grid.Based on this rowindex i want to fetch data from database and display on form.
How to get the rowindex of grid ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rowindex in GridView when OnCommand argument used in the field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740110/how-to-get-rowindex-in-gridview-when-oncommand-argument-used-in-the-field)

Answer (score 1):

Cast the sender to the `CheckBox` and use it's `NamingContainer` property to find the `GridViewRow`:

```
protected void Checkbox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
    // load data ...
}
```